# Find size of rectangles to fill area

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I got trouble need your help:

I'm working on a program that shows `n` videos in tiling mode (aka, videos wall, `c` columns and `r` rows). The `n` is arbitrary, the videos have same size (`W x H`) and we have `W / H` ratio, the size of wall is fixed, how can I get best set of `c`, `r`, `W` and `H` when `n` changes? The best set defined as: `W` and `H` is maximum values and videos fill maximum area of the wall.

I have taken a look at Packing Problem but still can't solve my problem above, can someone help me this? Thank you very much!

Comment: How can this be solved w/o knowing the dimensions of the wall?

Comment: It would take a C program very little time to run a loop to work out the best arrangement. Number of videos in each row from `1` to `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to place `n` rectangles with fixed `C=W/H` ratio on the wall with given `Width` and `Height`

Let rectangle height is h (unknown yet), width is w = C * h

Every row of grid contains

```
 nr =  Floor(Width / (C * h))   // rounding down
```

Every column contains

```
nc = Floor(Height / h)
```

Write inequality

```
n <= nc * nr
n <=  Floor(Width / (C * h)) * Floor(Height / h)
```

and solve it (find maximal possible `h` value)  for unknown h

For real values of parameters `h` might be found getting initial approximate value:

```
 h0 = Ceil(Sqrt(Width * Height / (n * C)))
```

and decrementing h value until inequality  becomes true