# filling parent container with changing number of child video elements, each with aspect ratio

Tags: css, video, geometry

I have a resizable parent element containing an ever-changing number of video elements.  Each video should maintain a width/height aspect ratio of 4/3.  As the total size of the parent is stretched and changed, each video element should resize itself so as to maximize the total area of video space, or to minimize the unused (non-video) area within the parent.

I feel like this should be relatively easy yet here I am hours later... what am I forgetting from childhood geometry?

There are no constraints on css elements I can use - I've tried with grids and flexbox layouts, all to little-to-no avail.

Comment: Algorithmic approach is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174158/find-size-of-rectangles-to-fill-area/45174396#45174396),  but perhaps there are some css-specific means to solve the problem.

Comment: @MBo that solution worked and it's good enough for me!  I'm not sure how to give you credits beyond upvoting your comment.  If you want to answer I'll accept and upvote.  Thanks

Comment: OK, answer is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is to place `n` rectangles with fixed `C=W/H = 4/3` ratio on the rectangular container with given `Width` and `Height`

Let scaled rectangle height is `h` (unknown yet), width is `w = C * h`

Every row of grid contains `nr` small rectangles

```
nr =  Floor(Width / (C * h))   // rounding down
```

Every column contains `nc` rows

```
nc = Floor(Height / h)
```

Write inequality

```
n <= nc * nr
n <=  Floor(Width / (C * h)) * Floor(Height / h)
```

and solve it for unknown `h` (find maximal possible `h` value)

For real values of parameters `h` might be found getting initial approximate value:

```
h0 = Ceil(Sqrt(Width * Height / (n * C)))   //rounding up
```

and decrementing `h` value until inequality becomes true